# Loading view trying to remove previous view from stack

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Scratching my head on this:

I have a viewController with a "loading..." view that is called when I load another viewController with a MapKit view which searches for a location.

On this "Loading..." view there is a cancel button which when clicked switches the view to the starting viewController. What is happening is when I switch to the starting view, the Map View still in the stack and updating the location in the background. I tried [locationmanager stopupdatinglocation] and I cannot get it to stop updating. All I need is to remove the map view from the stack alltogether,

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

This is the back button code from the loading... view:

```
-(void)back{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

Car_Park_AppViewController *appView = [[Car_Park_AppViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Car_Park_AppViewController" bundle:nil];
appView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:appView animated:YES];

[appView release];

}
```

map view code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;

loading *loadingView = [[loading alloc] init];

[super.view addSubview:loadingView.view];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;           locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude; 
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
MyManager *mng = [MyManager sharedManager];
mng.startLocation = newLocation;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=.00001;
span.longitudeDelta=.00001;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
region.span=span;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE]; 

i++;

NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[mng.endLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"Accuracy %f",newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);

if ((locationAge < 5.0) && (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 30.1)){    
     [self recLocation];
     i=0;

 }
haveAlreadyReceivedCoordinates = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UINavigationController:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/

Then you will have a stack of views where you can push and pop views, just like you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Roosevelt, I will have a look at that, but there must be a way to remove the map view from the stack...

Comment: Add this code to the Back() function:
[self removeFromSuperView];

Comment: Thanks, but it would dismiss the loading view and the map will still be there, because the map is a different view...

Comment: Then you should remove a view that displaying the map. [mapviewName removeFromSuperView];

Answer (score 0):

Have some flag for that. Once the cancel is pressed, set that flag to NO. And sont reload the view if the flag is NO.

Comment: Thanks Gomathi, but I need to remove the view from the stack, the map view will get reloaded from the starting view if necessary